# datetime in selenium python throwing error

Tags: python, selenium, datetime

Below code gives error as 'friday' no defined. If anything is missing, please help me with the same. Also if I interchange the position of 'friday' and 'prev_day' variables with if else, i get the error message with 'prev_day' not defined.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import datetime


d = datetime.date.today()

if d.weekday() == 0:
    tdelta = datetime.timedelta(days=3)
    friday = d - tdelta


elif d.weekday() in range(1,5):
    tdelta1 = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    prev_day = d - tdelta1


class ClassName(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\sameerj\IdeaProjects\chromedriver.exe")


    def test_as_on_date(self):

        driver = self.driver
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.get("website")
        login = driver.find_element_by_id("Email")
        login.send_keys("email")
        password = driver.find_element_by_id("Password")
        password.send_keys("password")
        password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        driver.find_element_by_id("menu_name").click()
        driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("page name").click()
        date = driver.find_element_by_id("lblAsOn").text
        new = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%m/%d/%Y')
        data_date = new.date()

        if data_date == friday:
            print("Data as on", friday, "for page name")
        elif data_date == prev_day:
            print("Data as on", prev_day, "for page name")
        else:
            print("Data update required.")
        driver.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a common type of mistake

let me break it down your mistake

```
if d.weekday() == 0:
    tdelta = datetime.timedelta(days=3)
    friday = d - tdelta


elif d.weekday() in range(1,5):
    tdelta1 = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    prev_day = d - tdelta1
```

---

**if we execute your program**

if `d.weekday() == 0` holds false

then  it will go to

`elif d.weekday() in range(1,5):`

but your `friday = d - tdelta` is in `if` condition. that's why its shows error

to solve that you must define `friday` outside `if` condition and reassign value in your `if` condition

**you can solve it like this**

```
friday = None
prev_day = None
d = datetime.date.today()

if d.weekday() == 0:
    tdelta = datetime.timedelta(days=3)
    friday = d - tdelta


elif d.weekday() in range(1,5):
    tdelta1 = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    prev_day = d - tdelta1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nihal, it worked for today. I will have to wait till Monday for the other case. I think it will work. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: Will confirm the code next week and it all conditions are passed then accept.

Answer (score 0):

```
new = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,'%m/%d/%Y')
data_date = new.strftime("%A")
```

This will give you the name of the day (Eg: Friday), then you can compare as you are doing,

```
if data_date == "Friday":
        print("Data as on",data_date , "for page name")
```

And for previous days comparison, you have to do,

`tdelta1 = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
prev_day = (new - tdelta1).strftime("%A")`

before doing,

```
elif data_date == prev_day:
        print("Data as on", prev_day, "for page name")
```

When you replaced Friday with prev_day, you are getting the error because of python interpreter is finding that variable first which is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You better write:

```
d = datetime.date.today()

if d.weekday() == 0:
    tdelta = datetime.timedelta(days=3)
    prev_day = None
    friday = d - tdelta
elif d.weekday() in range(1, 5):
    tdelta1 = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    prev_day = d - tdelta1
    friday = None
```

And my suggestion for you is to use Python IDEs, they highlight such errors.

Also I believe this checks could be done using the [calendar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/calendar.html) module